# Pandas df.fillna(method = 'pad') not working on 28000 row df

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Have been trying to just replace the NaN values in my DataFrame with the last valued item however this does not seem to do the job. Just wondering if anyone else has this same issue or what could be causing this problem.

```
In [16]: ABCW.info()
Out[16]:<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
         DatetimeIndex: 692 entries, 2014-10-22 10:30:00 to 2015-05-21   16:00:00
         Data columns (total 6 columns):
         Price              692 non-null float64
         Volume             692 non-null float64
         Symbol_Num         692 non-null object
         Actual Price       577 non-null float64
         Market Cap Rank    577 non-null float64
         Market Cap         577 non-null float64
         dtypes: float64(5), object(1)
         memory usage: 37.8+ KB


In [18]: ABCW.fillna(method = 'pad')

In [19]: ABCW.info()
Out [19]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
         DatetimeIndex: 692 entries, 2014-10-22 10:30:00 to 2015-05-21 16:00:00
         Data columns (total 6 columns):
         Price              692 non-null float64
         Volume             692 non-null float64
         Symbol_Num         692 non-null object
         Actual Price       577 non-null float64
         Market Cap Rank    577 non-null float64
         Market Cap         577 non-null float64
         dtypes: float64(5), object(1)
         memory usage: 37.8+ KB
```

There is no change in the number of non-null values and there is still all the preexisting NaN values that were previously in the data frame

Comment: please provide a way to reproduce the error you saw.

Comment: Where are the NaN values located? If they are all located in the beginning of the frame, this would explain why they are not filled with pad/ffill

Comment: Located at the end of the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the 'pad' method. This is basically a forward fill. See examples at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

I am reproducing the relevant example here,

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
        one       two     three
a       NaN -0.282863 -1.509059
c       NaN  1.212112 -0.173215
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
h       NaN -0.706771 -1.039575

In [34]: df.fillna(method='pad')
Out[34]: 
        one       two     three
a       NaN -0.282863 -1.509059
c       NaN  1.212112 -0.173215
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
h -2.104569 -0.706771 -1.039575
```

This method will not do a backfill. You should also consider doing a backfill if you want all your NaNs to go away. Also, 'inplace= False' by default. So you probably want to assign results of the operation back to ABCW.. like so,

```
ABCW = ABCW.fillna(method = 'pad')
ABCW = ABCW.fillna(method = 'bfill')
```

Comment: This is a point in time database, back filling would imply having knowledge of the future when that is a false assumption. I have tried this and understand the example given in the pandas docs. fillna() still leaves my data with holes in random places.

Comment: hmmm,   have tried to do a fillna with 'inplace=True'

Comment: What does in place do?

Comment: If, 'inplace =True' then the results of the fillna will be stored in the same df. If  'inplace=False' then the results of the fillna will be returned and not changes will be make to the df